# MaterialUI Autocomplete - Disable option after selection

Tags: material-ui

How to disable the selected option in the list of options in autocomplete MUI?

For example, after selecting option "b", it should be disabled.

[image: example]

```
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      freeSolo
      id="free-solo-demo"
      options={["a", "b", "c"]}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="freeSolo"
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material UI Autocomplete]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `getOptionDisabled` prop. You just have to pass a function to this prop which says to disable the option if already been selected.

There is another prop available in this component called `filterSelectedOptions`, which filters out the selected option.

You can find both of these working examples over here [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-efppkp?file=App.tsx)

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);
const options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  <Autocomplete
    multiple
    freeSolo
    options={options}
    value={selectedOptions}

    //disabling selected options
    getOptionDisabled={(option) =>
      selectedOptions.some((selectedOption) => selectedOption === option)
    }

    onChange={(_, value) => {
      setSelectedOptions(value);
    }}

    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="Multiple values"
        placeholder="Favorites"
      />
    )}
  />
```